# Postback request with gridview giving strange output

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 protected void gvRequest_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                bm.DeleteBookRequest(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                GetBooks();
            GetRequest();
            }
        }

    <asp:GridView ID="gvBooks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Id"
            BorderStyle="None" OnRowCommand="gvBooks_RowCommand" CssClass="gvBooks" CellPadding="5"
            CellSpacing="7" ForeColor="Blue" OnRowDeleting="gvBooks_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Title") %>' runat="server"
                            ID="lb_Id">Select</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Title") %>' runat="server"
                            ID="lb_Title">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvReviews" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gvReviews_RowCommand"
            OnRowDeleting="gvReviews_RowDeleting" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="7" ForeColor="Blue">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Review" HeaderText="Review" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' runat="server"
                            ID="lb_IdDel">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvRequest" runat="server" onrowcommand="gvRequest_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

when I click on the delete linkbutton the output is a blank page.

The view source after the click button is clicked is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" 
async="true"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="http://sg.perion.com/v1.1/js/gt.js" 
async="true" onload="null"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>

internal void DeleteBookRequest(int id)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Delete from bookrequest where id=@id";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.BigInt, 19, "id").Value = id;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();            
        }
```

Comment: can you show us what had you done in DeleteBookRequest function ? bcz without seeing it we can found the problem.

Comment: thanks, Have you debug it ? are you getting any error ? and after deleting do you redirect to any other page ?

Comment: I am not getting any error, just a blank page with no content

Comment: It looks like that the following functions are not working. GetBooks(); GetRequest(); They are not binding the data to your grid due to which you are getting empty page. Check these functions.

Comment: The functions work for Get request(Not postback), so they should work for postback requests as well. Why do I get a blank page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15797/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-waqar-janjua)

Comment: Hey Waqar, I solved it. I was missing the rowdeleted and rowdeleting function. Silly me. Thanks to you for suggesting about rowedit function which led me to the solution. Thanks!!!